# Registry logic in Zend 2

Tags: zend-framework2

I just started looking at Zend Framework 2 and just cant get one thing.

At start you load your Autoloader for example StandardAutoloader.

Then for example you call the db adapter lets say something like this.

$adapter = new Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter($configArray);

and how is that registered to use in php. In Zend 1 i see its done with Zend_Registry, but in Zend 2 there is no such thing.

So if i want to call $adapter somewhere in the module how can i do it like $this->adapter-> ...

Comment: did you take a look at my answer? does it respond to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Registry, in ZF2 you have [the service manager](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.service-manager.quick-start.html).

in your Module.php, you use the function

```
 public function getServiceConfig() {
    return array (
            'factories' => array (

                 'adapter' => function ($sm) {
                              $adapter = new Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter($configArray);
                              return $adapter;

                    }  

            )
    );
}
```

In any controller you can use:

```
 $adapter = $this->getServiceLocator ()->get ( 'adapter' );
```

You can learn almost all you need about service manager in [this blog post](http://samsonasik.wordpress.com/?s=service%20manager) and [this other](http://blog.evan.pro/introduction-to-the-zend-framework-2-servicemanager)